# AdWhril adds not displaying and even not posting to twitter when upload to app store

Tags: iphone, twitter, adwhirl

i have implemented AdWhirl in my app and when i create build in xcode and install on my iphone then adds are showing perfectly but when i download the app from the app store then adds not receiving.

i have another issue relate to twitter and that is when i have post to twitter using TWTweetComposerViewController and posting to twitter is perfectly fine but when i try to post from my app downloading from AppStore then it shows error Cannot send tweet

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer the problem was that in adwhirl app configration there was setting for Google Admob and iAd but here was not sdk for Google Ad Mob in my app bundle. when i add ad mob sdk to my app then it works perfectly fine.

and in twitter i have dismissed twitter controller twice in my code so there might be reason for not working well but when i deleted one dismiss statement then it works fine now.